# Removing Space in my table field using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Table named SubSituationType has a name field. It has space at the end of the name.

For Eg:

```
SubSituationType.all.collect(&:name) gives
```

`["Pos/Neg Space - Design ", "Pantone Match ", .....]`

I need to remove the space for all such values. How to do it?

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and rails 2.3.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SubSituationType.all.map { |type| type.name.strip }
```

And it's better to use `.pluck` over `.all`:

```
SubSituationType.pluck(:name).map(&:strip)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-strip)

```
SubSituationType.all.map(&:name).map(&:strip)
```

In Rails >= 3.0.0 use [String#squish](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/String/squish)

```
SubSituationType.pluck(:name).map(&:squish)
```

[ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method available on Rails >= 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql,

you can achieve this with following query, but this would update values in name column:--

```
UPDATE `sub_situation_types` SET `name` = TRIM( `name` );
```

Or with Rails you can use 'pluck' as suggested by xdazz, but this won't update values in name column.
like:--

```
SubSituationType.all.map { |type| type.name.strip }
```

or

```
SubSituationType.pluck(:name).map(&:strip)
```